# Textarea event in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my application then is some textarea with class "contentBlock".

and i am using for following code in backbone view:

```
 'change textarea': 'updateText'
```

but the updateText function is not getting fired.

I want to fire the event when any text got change in the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... sadly, as we have too few elements to provide any answer, I'm simply providing you a working, simple example:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'change textarea': 'test'
  },
  test: function() {
    alert();   
  }
});

new View({el: 'div'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSgvy/

So, based on common mistakes: make sure your events are bounded to your view's element (if you specify an element which doesn't exist or you change it the wrong way afterwards, they won't), and make sure your textarea actually is a descendant of your view's element. Also, the way you do it, the textarea must not be the view's element itself.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the **keyup** event (or some other key event) to listen for the text changing in the text area.  Using *Loamhoof's* example:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'keyup textarea': 'test'
    },
    test: function() {
        alert();   
    }
});

new View({el: 'div'});
```

Comment: The `keyup` event is only fired when one is interacting with the keyboard. It doesn't work if one enters e.g. an emoji using the CTRL+CMD+SPACE key combo on OSX!